# Can JavaScript maintain any state after a reload?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to have JavaScript hold any variables through a reload?

If the user hits the reload button, is there any state that is kept by JavaScript, once a page is reloaded?

Comment: This is now the *third* time I've had to correct your spelling of [tag:javascript] in the past few days.  *Please* take more care when selecting tags!

Comment: Indeed, you gained the ability to create new tags once you hit 1500 reputation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Variable usage on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestions

- Cookie
- HTML 5 Web Storage https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Either way, you'll need to write your own read/write methods to store your state.

Comment: That is almost too easy to believe, HTML 5.

Comment: IE7 does not support it at all.

Comment: HTML5 Storage is great. Here's a more complete api: http://php-html.net/tutorials/html5-local-storage-guide/ . Some Google doodle games use Storage to keep state, so you can actually change the values if you want to go to a different point in the game. E.g. the Turing doodle (copied here: http://www.websonic.nl/googledoodles/turing/index.php) uses the key `doodle-turing-p` to remember which puzzle you've finished.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to utilize cookies to maintain your state. If you're using jQuery I sugest you look into jQuery Cookie:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

small data (2KByte) can be stored in the URL suffix

fragment ID: `//host/path#fragment-id`

query string: `//host/path?query-string`

the fragment-id-method is used here:
http://xkcd-map.rent-a-geek.de/
on every dragend-event, the URL is changed
to reflect the current position on the map

special chars mut be urlencode-d

related: [hot reloading](https://github.com/hasura/awesome-live-reloading), [reloadable code](https://figwheel.org/docs/reloadable_code), [figwheel.clj](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-kj2qwJa_E), [react.js hot loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader)